# clustered st_convex_hull

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to obtain a polygon from each group of points "G" but I obtain only one single polygon for all the points.
I grouped data by the G variable but it doesn't work.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

    data.frame(ID = 1:10,
               X = sample(1:10, 10),
               Y = sample(1:10, 10),
               G= c("a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","c","c","c")) %>% 
    st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
    group_by(G) %>% 
    st_union() %>% 
    st_convex_hull() %>% 
    plot()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To union on groups use `summarise`:

```
data.frame(ID = 1:10,
               X = sample(1:10, 10),
               Y = sample(1:10, 10),
               G= c("a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","c","c","c")) %>% 
    st_as_sf(coords = c("X", "Y")) %>% 
    group_by(G) %>% 
    summarise() %>% 
    st_convex_hull() %>% 
    plot()
```

[image]